# CSS o JS (Header)

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Colegas buen día, les comento.  tengo un header con su navegación  y un texto sencillo, la cuestión es que quiero que este header  siempre cubra toda la pantalla sin importar que tan larga o corta sea la pantalla, cuando la pantalla es muy corta no se me muestra parte del header y cuando es muy larga muestra informacion de la siguiente sección,. necesito algo asi como un header responsivo verticalmente (espero no caer en un error cuando digo responsivo verticalmente)
alguien sabe cual seria la propiedad de css que me permite hacer eso?, HE googleado pero no hay nada que me permita hacer eso (solo css3) no bootstrap o tailwind ni otros,
!nuevamente! no quiero ni que se me oculte ni que se me muestre mas información a parte del header en la pantalla completa de cualquier dispositivo por corto o largo que sea, agradezco su colaboración

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y como proveer un [mcve]

Comment: Como dice @BetaM, El ejemplo mínimo verificable es que agregues tu código para verificar y dar solución

Comment: min-height: 100vh;

Answer (score 0):

Si entendi de  manera correcta tu pregunta, tenes un header el cual queres que ocupe el mismo tamaño y la misma informacion en todos los dispositivos/pantallas?
De ser asi, le podes cambiar las especificaciones con el @media. Tene en cuenta que este "codigo" sirve para dar unas especificaciones en cada pantalla.
Es decir, que si tu codigo tiene por ejemplo un texto de 40px en una pc, en el media, podes poner que tenga 20px y sigue manteniendo todas las otras especificaciones. Un saludo y espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/390390)